# My AJAX wont run the SUCCESS Function but executes my controller, JAVA

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I'm trying to execute my controller and get the return string to be used for my alert message, but my success function won't work. It executes the controller but does not execute the success function. The error executes but does not display any message.
BELOW IS THE AJAX

```js
var jsonData = {
    "appIDHidden": appname,
    "txtypeHidden": txtype,
    "ipaddress": ipaddress
   };
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "checkaccesspermission",
     data: jsonData,
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data) {
     if(data != "exists"){
      alert('Permission Already Exists!');
      return false;
     }else{
      alert('Add Permission test Succesful!');
      return true; 
     }
     alert('test123');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, thrownError)
    {
     alert(thrownError+jsonData[1]);
    },
     async: false
   });
```

BELOW IS THE CONTROLLER

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/checkaccesspermission", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String checkaccesspermission(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") IpAccessManagementModel loginForm, Model model,
            HttpSession session, BindingResult result,HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestParam("ipaddress") String ipaddress,
            @RequestParam("txtypeHidden") String txtype,
            @RequestParam("appIDHidden") String appID) throws IOException{
            System.out.println("CHECKACCESSPERMISSIONs");
            IpAccessManagementModel sub = new IpAccessManagementModel();
            sub.setAppName(appID);
            sub.setTxtType(txtype);
            sub.setIpAddress(ipaddress);
            System.out.println(ipaddress);
            ipAccessMGTDAO.addPermission(sub);
            String resultCheckExist = ipAccessMGTDAO.checkAccessPermission(sub);
            System.out.println("checkResult:|"+resultCheckExist+"|");
            return resultCheckExist;
    }
```

Comment: Remove `dataType: 'json',`

Comment: I tried that, still doesn't work :( thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, i got it to work by adding @public ResponseBody on my Controller :`@RequestMapping(value="/checkaccesspermission", method=RequestMethod.POST)
       public @ResponseBody
         String checkaccesspermission`